# jquery - get elements by tag within a specific div?

Tags: jquery, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get all input elements within a certain div, but it seems to return all inputs on any given page... is there a way to do this?

```
if($('#umi-form')) {
          var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `if()` test will always evaluate `true`. You should use the `length` property in the `if()`.

```
var uform = $('#umi-form');
if(uform.length) {
    var inputs = uform.find('input');
}
```

If you were hoping to get a `nodeList` instead of a jQuery object, do this:

```
var uform = $('#umi-form');
if(uform[0]) {
    var inputs = uform[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It can be done like this:

```
var $inputs = $('#umi-form input');
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript first...

```
document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
```

will get all the `input`s in the `document` (*"page"*). Whilst

```
document.getElementById( 'umi-form' ).getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
```

will get all the `input`s in `#umi-form`.

In this case, the calling of `getElementsByTagName` is on the *element* before the period. If we call it on the `document` we get all the elements with the named tag on the *page*. If we call it on a *child* element of the `document`, then we get only the elements with the named tag from within that child.

You'll always get all the elements with the named tag that are within the *element* the method is called on. If however you want to get at just one of them, use

```
target_element.getElementsByTagName( 'tag-name' )[ index ];
```

where `index` is an *integer* within the range of the returned `length`, which is obtained with

```
target_element.getElementsByTagName( 'tag-name' ).length;
```

Since jQuery is a JavaScript library, it's advisable to get a good understanding of JS before attempting to use jQuery IMO.